# Querying the corresponding key from the JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have the following json structure in the mongo db.

```
{
"branch": [
    {
    "section": [
        {
            "sub": "edc",
            "time": "one hour",
            "frequency": "3"
        },
        {
            "sub": "bee",
            "time": "two hours",
            "frequency": "4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "section": [
        {
            "sub": "ss",
            "time": "one hour",
            "frequency": "2"
        },
        {
            "sub": "ms",
            "time": "two hours",
            "frequency": "5"
        }
    ]
}
 ]
}
```

I want to perform a query such that it returns only values of the following key

branch.section.sub

After the query I want the output like

```
edc
bee
ss
ms
```

Comment: Hint: If you didn't use a question mark you probably didn't ask a question...

Comment: Try `jsonpath` library

Answer (score 1):

Use the [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/) of find:

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {"branch.section.sub":1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with RickyA --
but you might want to suppress the _id from the results:

Also, if you just want the output to be the values of the field, you could try with the forEach function to print -- something like:

```
db.test.find( {}, 
              {"branch.section.sub":1, _id: 0} 
            ).forEach( function (x) { 
                                       for (i = 0; i < x.branch.length; i++) { 
                                           section = x.branch[i].section; 
                                           for (j = 0; j < section.length; j++ ) { 
                                                print( section[j].sub);    
                                           } 
                                       } 
                                     } )
```